# Bash text parsing golf

Tags: linux, svn, bash, code-golf

I am writing a shell script to, among other things, determine the last time a branch was made in a subversion repository.  The following code works:

```
        DEV='http://some/svn/server/'
        BRANCH='some/repos/branches/'
        LAST_UPDATE=`svn list http://$DEV$BRANCH | sort -r`
        LAST_UPDATE=${LAST_UPDATE:0:10}
```

But I am not liking the last two lines.  How can I combine them together?

```
NOTE: 

`svn list http://some/svn/server | sort -r`
will return a list of folders such as:
2009-01-12/
2009-01-11/
...
2009-01-01/
```

I am just trying to remove the trailing slash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
    LAST_UPDATE=`svn list http://$DEV$BRANCH | sort -r | awk -F\/ '{print $1}'`
```

I've not tested it, and I'm not sure if the quotes inside the back-ticks will cause any problems, but otherwise I can't see why it wouldn't work...

Ben

Comment: i am theman, but you are the man as well.  I almost typed that as "-FV" at first then i realized you were escaping the slash.  Nice one, thanks!

Comment: No worries! I love awk. It nearly always seems to help in situations like this.

Comment: sed and awk are two beasts i have only recently became brave enough to start messing with

Comment: `cut -d/ -f1` is a shorter way of doing what awk is doing there.  `sed -e 's:/.*::'` would work too, if you want everything before the first slash (as the awk and cut solutions do).  `sed -e 's:/$::'` will only trim a trailing slash.  Learn your tools!  :)

Answer (score 1):

Another, perhaps more robust suggestion, would be to use `basename`:

```
LAST_UPDATE=`svn list http://$DEV$BRANCH | sort -r | xargs -i basename {}`
```

The key advantage is that `basename` knows about path syntax and will produce a canonical representation no matter what oddball file names you throw at it.